# How to host example data for a R-packages on Github

Tags: r, github

I'm experimenting with GitHub and I created a little package for my colleagues to use. They install it with the `devtools` package and `install_github()` function directly in `R`. I also have some example data and a R-Markdown file that shows the usage of all functions in the package [and can be published via GitHub Pages](https://resources.github.com/whitepapers/github-and-rstudio/).

I would like to know what would be the best practice to enable others to use this example data to learn the package.

I can think of two different options:

1. Host the data in a separate directory which is not part of the  installation and tell people to download it manually or use something like the  `download.file()` function from `R` at the beginning of the example script to download all data that could be packed into a .zip.
2. Make the data part of the package installation, however this would require the data to be fairly small which is difficult in my particular case (data is 10MB).

Ideally the examples in the R-documentation (`.Rd` files in the `man` folder) could also use the same examples as in the markdown file. also in this case, option (2) seems to be favorable.

Could anybody give me some advice what would be the best way to go, sort of the "industry standard" if there is any.

Comment: I once saved some data in `.Rds` format (`saveRDS`), uploaded to figshare and then read it in direclty from the URL (see line 29 here: https://gist.github.com/adibender/28041453a2a8c3e42c09484a55668d55)

Comment: I'd say 1) is a better option. You can even create a function for doing such work and include it as a part of your package. You can find an example of what my team did for distributing an example corpus for NLP. https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda.corpora/blob/master/R/download.R